# How to prove that the inverse of a conjugate matrix is equal to the conjugate of an inverse of the same matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I am a little confused as to proving that $(C^*)^{-1} = (C^{-1})^*$ where $C$ is an invertible matrix which is complex.

Initially, I thought that it would have something to do with the identity matrix where $CC^{-1}=C^{-1}$. $C = I$ but don't seem to be getting anywhere with that.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you apply the $*$ operator to the identity $CC^{-1} = I$, knowing that the inverse is unique?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net so would I be right in saying that I*=I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to use $(AB)^\ast =B^\ast A^\ast$ with $A=C,\,B=C^{-1}$. Both sides are $I$; the right-hand side must therefore be $(C^\ast)^{-1}C^\ast$.

Answer (score 3):

*: conjugation (not Hermitian)
\begin{equation}
I=AA^{-1}=A^*(A^{-1})^* 
\end{equation}
since $I=I^*$.

Also,
\begin{equation}
I=A^*(A^*)^{-1}. 
\end{equation}

Therefore
\begin{equation}
A^*(A^*)^{-1}=A^*(A^{-1})^*. 
\end{equation}

Multiplying from left by $(A^*)^{-1}$ you get 
\begin{equation}
(A^*)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^*. 
\end{equation}